# react .map does not render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, render

I want to loop through a props **screenshots** but it's not working for me! I used to do it in other components and it was working. I'm losing my mind :(

please find below my code:

```
              {screenshots && <h2>Hello</h2>}
```

this works and rendered perfectly.

but when I do a loop like

```
{screenshots && screenshots.length && screenshots.map(screenshot => {
    <div className="container img--container" key={screenshot.id}>
        <SVG
        className="icon remove--icon"
        src={removeCircle}
        />
       <img src={screenshot.image} title={"screenshot"} className="p-absolute"/>
    </div>
})}
```

what's inside the loop doesn't get rendered!
and the console doesn't show any error.

please any help?

Comment: you're not returning anything from `.map()`. wrap the content like `.map(screenshot => ( ... );`

Comment: It's not returning anything, use () instead of {} in .map(screenshot => ())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing return!! You can use "()" to return immediate.

```
{screenshots && screenshots.length && screenshots.map(screenshot => (
    <div className="container img--container" key={screenshot.id}>
        <SVG
        className="icon remove--icon"
        src={removeCircle}
        />
       <img src={screenshot.image} title={"screenshot"} className="p-absolute"/>
    </div>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `map`, you have to be careful what to put after the `=>`.
If you have to process elements of the array when mapping, do this:

```
array.map(a => { 
  // Javascript here
  return(
    <div>JSX here!</div>
  );
});
```

If you just have to render JSX, do this:

```
array.map(a => (
    <div>JSX here!</div>
));
```

Since `=> ()` is implicitly returning the stuff between `()`.

Answer (score 0):

In arrow functions **curly brackets are used for closures**. So it will wrap your function.

If you use arrow function **with curly brackets**, you have to use `return`. Like this:

```js
screenshots.map(screenshot => {
    console.log('I can do whatever I like here...');
    return 'but I have to return something!'
});
```

Arrow function **without curly brackets** automatically returns your statement and it has to be used **only with one statement**.

```js
screenshots.map(screenshot => 
   'It returns this string without using word `return`!'
);
```

---

Your code should look like this (with **curly brackets** and **return**):

```js
{screenshots && screenshots.length && screenshots.map(screenshot => {
    console.log('Wow! I am in arrow function! I have to return something.');
    return 
        <div className="container img--container" key={screenshot.id}>
           <SVG className="icon remove--icon" src={removeCircle}/>
           <img src={screenshot.image} title={"screenshot"} className="p-absolute"/>
        </div>
})}
```

or you can just **delete curly brackets** like this:

```js
{screenshots && screenshots.length && screenshots.map(screenshot =>
    <div className="container img--container" key={screenshot.id}>
        <SVG className="icon remove--icon" src={removeCircle}/>
       <img src={screenshot.image} title={"screenshot"} className="p-absolute"/>
    </div>
)}
```

---

You can read more about [arrow functions at w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp).